# Taking Photo of Screen with VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

Currently I have the following VB.NET code to make a screenshot of my desktop, but it only takes a picture of the active screen:

```
Public Function SaveScreen(ByVal theFile As String) As Boolean

        Try
            SendKeys.Send("%{PRTSC}")          '<alt + printscreen>
            Application.DoEvents()

            Dim data As IDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject()

            If data.GetDataPresent(GetType(System.Drawing.Bitmap)) Then
                Dim bmp As Bitmap = CType(data.GetData(GetType(System.Drawing.Bitmap)), Bitmap)
                bmp.Save(theFile, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            End If
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(0)      'save memory by removing the image from the clipboard
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try

    End Function
```

The following code is how I execute the above function, if it makes any difference, which I don't think it does:

```
SaveScreen("C:\Lexer_trace\screen.png")
```

Now, I need to be able to take a picture of the entire screen, not just the focused window. How would I do this?

Thanks in advance,

Logan

Comment: [this link](http://vbtab.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-take-a-screenshot-print-screen-using-vb-net.html) may explain it well..

Answer (score 4):

You should be using `System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen()`
[See Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yfzc507.aspx) to copy from a screen

Simply query the full size of the screen to pass in as points.
Something similar to what you have with `.CopyFromScreen()`

```
Public Sub SaveScreen(filename As String)

    Dim screenSize = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize
    Dim bitmap = New Bitmap(screenSize.Width, screenSize.Height)
    Dim g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)

    g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, 0), screenSize)
    g.Flush()
    bitmap.Save(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Your comment says you are sending `alt + printscreen` which does just capture the currently active window.

If you just send `printscreen` it should capture the whole desktop.

Comment: I just tried that, and it does not work. Any other suggestions? I even tried +{PRTSC}...

Comment: @Logan - no other than doing using the system calls.

Answer (score 0):

Well the immediate fix would be to send only print screen:

```
SendKeys.Send("{PRTSC}")
```

But that's a lame hack at best. To take a screenshot of the screen reliably, you need to use P/Invoke to `GetDC` of the desktop handle (0) and `BitBlt` its contents into a `Bitmap`. Don't forget to `ReleaseDC` the desktop's DC before you're done.

Or use [`Graphics.CopyFromScreen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without sending the Alt key too?

Something like:

```
SendKeys.Send("{PRTSC}")          '<printscreen>
```

Comment: I just tried that, and it does not work. Any other suggestions? I even tried +{PRTSC}...